# Barcodescanner Camera Auto Focus Exception in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent, perspectivecamera

can anyone know why some device through exception when camera on following exception through i was use barcodescanner. It initially works fine but after trying to auto focus two to three times i get a RuntimeException: autoFocus failed:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: autoFocus failed
   at android.hardware.Camera.native_autoFocus(Camera.java)
   at android.hardware.Camera.autoFocus(Camera.java:1126)
   at com.maruticourier.android.ZBarScannerActivity$1.run(ZBarScannerActivity.java:175)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```